# powershell and VScode UTF8 encoding issues

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I written a bit of powershell to invoke an app - but oddly the VScode terminal outputs strange characters and also includes them in variables I'm setting; While the app logs external to VSCode are showing the proper characters as I would expect.

I've made sure UTF8 is set in VScode but haven't been able to find the cause of this issue.

I did find a super old post that seems very similar though https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/utf-8-in-output-pane-is-not-displayed-correctly/429447

Here's the current VSCode output:

```
* My Pictures/Tony/AutomΓÇª22-07-13 16-43-54.heic: checking
 * My Pictures/Tony/AutomΓÇª22-07-14 11-03-00.heic: checking
 * My Pictures/Tony/AutomΓÇª22-07-14 11-03-01.heic: checking
```

vs the app logs look as expected:

```
2022/07/22 12:39:38.790860 DEBUG : My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2021-12-09 19-36-19.heic: Excluded
2022/07/22 12:39:38.790860 DEBUG : My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2021-12-09 13-52-56.heic: Excluded
2022/07/22 12:39:38.790860 DEBUG : My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2021-12-24 23-41-10.jpeg: Excluded
2022/07/22 12:39:38.790860 DEBUG : My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2021-12-25 09-35-05.jpeg: Excluded
2022/07/22 12:39:38.790860 DEBUG : My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2021-12-25 09-25-11.jpeg: Excluded
```

VScode version info:

```
Version: 1.69.2 (user setup)
Commit: 3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a
Date: 2022-07-18T16:12:52.460Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

Comment: Can you show how you invoke the app and display the output to VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW this solved my issue, even though its on the WP stackexchange.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/393600

Comment: This is the right way!